# which book can help me for self-learning VARIMA model?

Tags: time-series

I want to understand how working VARIMA model. I spend lot of time searching some articles about time series which can show me pictures and simple description, because formulas unachievable for me. I want to ask which book can help me for self-learning with VARIMA model?

---

Like answer on this post I want to give this link of great videos, the video will help many people who have same problem like I have. Thanks to the author  of  this video!

https://www.youtube.com/user/BCFoltz/videos

Comment: I'd recommend first trying to understand a sequence of models: AR models, MA models, ARMA models, ARIMA models - in that order. Those models are univariate. The VARMA model, which is multivariate, is basically just a collection of those models, so you'd do well to understand them first. The main difference will be the introduction of cross correlations, so details about estimation and the error covariance matrix will be important. Tsay's "Multivariate Time Series Analysis: With R and Financial Applications" could be useful to you. In my opinion, formulas are unavoidable, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, you could try an undergraduate econometrics textbook such as Stock and Watson's "Introduction to Econometrics" then increase the difficulty by resorting to something more advanced, such as Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis". By the way, VAR models are more popular than VARMA models (at least in economics), so maybe this introductory article, which doesn't contain formulas, will be useful to you: [Vector Autoregressions](http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.15.4.101) by Stock and Watson (2001, Journal of Economic Perspectives).

Answer (score 2):

VARIMA model are discussed in http://www.amazon.co.uk/Time-Series-Analysis-Univariate-Multivariate/dp/0201159112 . It has exanples using MTS software. VAR models are easier to compute which is why they are more popular but who said statistical analysis would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Luktepohl's "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis" or Tsay's "Multivariate Time Series," both of which are specifically dedicated to multivarate time series analysis. Both texts contain much more if you are so inclined to read beyond VARIMA. Tsay even has his own multivariate time series library for R and has exercises in the book that you can practice with.