# Groups of correlated time series prediction

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, correlation, missing-data

Consider two group of time series $X$ and $Y$. Both $X$ and $Y$ contain time series $\{x_0,..., x_N\}$ and $\{y_0,..., y_N\}$, respectively. Within each group, the time series are correlated and also there is correlation across the groups so that $(x_i, y_j)$ have non-zero correlation. The times series in $Y$ is sparely populated and $X$ has complete information. How might I design a model to fill in the missing data in $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

You have a VECTOR ARIMA problem (VARIMA) where you have k1 endogenous series ( the Y series ) and k2 exogenous series ( the X series ) . Identify a useful VARIMA model [which book can help me for self-learning VARIMA model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164799/which-book-can-help-me-for-self-learning-varima-model) and obtain the fitted values to help you fill in your "missing values"  also see a particular favorite of mine which I have some responsibility for ...  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Time-Series-Analysis-Univariate-Multivariate/dp/0201159112

I would strongly consider an iterative approach .... i.e. a number of passes due to the deleterious effect of lots of 0's to begin with in the Y's